# Virtualhost Config for Laravel not redirect to public folder

Tags: laravel, apache2

I have a problem when I deploy laravel with apache web server on Ubuntu 20 Server. My apache running on 8080 port. When I access the laravel directory the project is not directed to the public folder. Even though I have made a virtualhost configuration

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.1.2:8080>
        ServerName admin-baledono.com
        ServerAlias www.admin-baledono.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@admin-baledono.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin-baledono.com/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/admin-baledono.com>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted

                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/admin-baledono.com-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/admin-baledono.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have disabled the default configuration file from virtual host in Apache. And enabled my virtualhost configuration.

I've also created a .htaccess file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the result is still the same. When I access my website, what is displayed is the contents of my project directory

Comment: Do u already check this https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04/?

Comment: @SokChanty I've been following it

Comment: still not work?

Comment: @SokChanty yes still not work

Comment: Where did you change your .htaccess file? on root or on public. If you specified your DocumentRoot on apache as `/var/www/html/admin-baledono.com/public` then you should update your htaccess in public folder.

Comment: @DeepeshThapa in the public directory there is already a .htaccess file, and I made another .htaccess file in the root as above.

Comment: could you try vhost file with  <VirtualHost *:80>  and remove Allow from all

Comment: Did you enable site?  I think the problem lies on setting up your virtual host file. What did you follow to setting up your apache config files?

Comment: Did you clear all your cache and route?